# Get RowCount With Date Comparasion in SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS. 
I have a dataset, my dataset brings data from a stored procedure.
one of the parameters of my sp is StartDate and another one is EndDate. Their type is datetime
And the table has a dateTime Column called Date.
I have two  gauges and I wanna bind  integer values to my gauges. 
First one is the count of rows where Date < DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,24,StartDate)
and te second is count of rows where Date > DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,24,StartDate)
How will I write the exact script. Whatever I wrote is not working.
I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the gauge Pointer value as something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Parameters!StartDate.Value, Fields!Date.Value) >= 1
    , 1
    , 0))
```

[image]

This is counting rows where the time difference is less than a day compared to the parameter `StartDate`. Just change it slightly to get those where the difference is at least a day:

```
=Sum(IIf(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Parameters!StartDate.Value, Fields!Date.Value) >= 1
    , 0
    , 1))
```

Worked fine for me in a quick test:

[image]

Comment: thanks I already find the same solution somehow a few minutes ago :) may I ask you something more? what do you suggest me to style my reports? I have devExpress but I cant use in SSRS. what about css or any other way to increase visual beauty?

Comment: Hi, @anzaidemirzoi, I don't think that's a question that can easily be answered in a comment - perhaps you should ask another question, although it's quite broad so maybe not a great fit for SO. Short answer, there's no easy way to use a theme for your reports, if that's what you're getting at... This is a useful link and has links to other articles that may help: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-with-style/